# How to add plugin to run configuration?

Tags: java, eclipse

I try to build a java project with eclipse.
During the complilation I have error `java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.` So I read that I need to add required plugins. I went to `Run Configuration -> Plug-ins tab`, push button `Add Required Plug-ins` and then `validate plug-ins`. I have my own plugin in the project. So I get `com.blablabla is missing`. How can I add my plugin to plugins list?

UPD: MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: %pluginName
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.blabla.cc; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 0.0.0.REL
Bundle-Activator: com.blabla.ui.cc.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: %providerName
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.core.expressions;bundle-version="3.4.1",
 com.blabla.core,
 com.blabla..shared,
 com.blabla.ui.core,
 com.blabla.ui,
 org.eclipse.jface.text,
 org.eclipse.ui.editors,
 org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor,
 org.eclipse.core.filesystem,
 org.eclipse.ui.ide,
 org.eclipse.ui.views,
 org.apache.axis,
 org.eclipse.wst.xml.core
Eclipse-LazyStart: true
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/SCESchemaCodeCcWorkbench.jar,
 lib/DebugUtils.jar,
 bin,
 icons,
 myApplicationUI.jar,
 lib/batik-awt-util.jar,
 lib/batik-bridge.jar,
 lib/batik-css.jar,
 lib/batik-dom.jar,
 lib/batik-ext.jar,
 lib/batik-gvt.jar,
 lib/batik-parser.jar,
 lib/batik-script.jar,
 lib/batik-svg-dom.jar,
 lib/batik-swing.jar,
 lib/batik-util.jar,
 lib/batik-xml.jar,
 lib/xml-apis-dom3.jar,
 lib/batik-transcoder.jar,
 lib/batik-anim.jar,
 lib/batik-codec.jar,
 lib/batik-extension.jar,
 lib/batik-gui-util.jar,
 lib/batik-svggen.jar,
 lib/xml-apis-ext.jar
Export-Package: com.blabla.sce.schema.code.ccworkbench,
 com.blabla.sce.schema.code.ccworkbench.types
Implementation-Version: 0.0.0.REL
Bundle-Localization: plugin
```

Comment: You mean to the target platform and then to your run configuration? Is your plugin error-free (and available in your workspace, or as a separate jar)?

Comment: I'm sure that plugin is error-free. It's available in my workspace. What's about target platform?

Comment: Could you share your MANIFEST.MF file?